# How to implement serversideSiderProps with context in nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

How to implement this same functionality in Nextjs version 13 to get dynamic query parmters and render on server side.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let {query}=context
  const res = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${query.itemid}`)
  let data = await res.json()
  return {
    props: {
      product:data
    }, 
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://youtu.be/IfJaGxIqijE?t=895, this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

getServerSideProps() does not exist in next js 13, all the files in the App directory are by default server components. so you do not need to call API into the getServerSideProps() function, you can just directly call the API.

check this out - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating